# Summation of binomial coefficients with indices having difference of 4

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

> Let  $S$ $=$  $\binom{n}3 $ $+$ $\binom{n}7$ $+$ $\binom{n}{11} $ $.....$

Find $S$.

This question can be solved by taking the difference of the binomial series of $\frac{-(1+x)^n - (1-x)^n}{2}$ and $\frac{(1+ix)^n - (1-ix)^n}{2i}$ , where $i^2$ $=$ $-1$ and substituting $x$ $=$ $1$ and dividing the resulting value by 2.

However, I wonder if the value of $S$ can be evaluated using calculus ? Please help me with this thought.

Comment: Do you know how to find $$\sum_{r=0}^{4r+2\le n}\binom n{4r+2}$$

Comment: I think op asking for power series methods like ogf, egf

Comment: @jeea maybe. What I had in mind was that we solve summations of binomial series using integration and differentiation of already known binomial expanions, so I wondered if this given series in question can be solved like that. I certainly did not think about power series, i was limited to thinking about the elementary methods. Definitely power series methods will also be a source of learning for me.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee by using algebra on already known binomial series ? then yes, just the way I did it in my question . By using calculus ? no. That's what my question is, how to do it using calculus.

Comment: @Shashank, Algebraic generalization of your problem : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266437/calculating-binomn0-binomn4-binomn8-cdots/3266466#3266466

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you. I understand the solution and I see that I applied the same method in my answer. My question, however is not about algebraic methods, I am asking that can calculus help in solving this summation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose 4k+3}$$
$$(1+x)^n=1+{n \choose 1} x+ {n \choose 2} x^2+ {n \choose 3}x^3+ {n \choose 4} x^4+...+{n \choose n}x^n~~~(1)$$
Let $z^4=1$ its roots are $1,a,a^2,a^3 (1,i,-1,-i)$, with $1+a+a^2+a^3=0$
Put $x=w$ in (1), then
putting $x=1,a,a^2,a^3(1,i,-1,-i)$ in (1) we get
$$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k},~ (1+a)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a^k, ~(1+a^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^{2k},$$ $$~(1+a^3)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a^{3k}$$
Multiplying these identities by $1, a, a^2, a^3$ respectively and adding them we get
$$2^n+a(1+a)^n+a^2(1+a^2)^n+a^3(1+a^3)= \sum_{k=0}^n (1+a^{k+1}+a^{2k+2}+a^{3k+3})
{n \choose k}~~~(2)$$
The term in the parenthesis in RHS of (2) is 1 only for$ k=3,7,11,15,...$, otherwise it vanishes.
So $$S=2^n+(1+i)^n+i^2(1+i^2)^n+i^3(1+i^3)^n= 2^ni[(1+i)^n-(1-i)^n]$$ $$=2^n-2^{n/2}~ 2\sin n\pi/4$$

Comment: I think this is correct and useful, *but* this is exactly what op was not asking, as in the question...