# Sum of a binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

I came across this question: Sum the series
$${6n \choose 0} + {6n \choose 3} + {6n \choose 6} + \cdots + {6n \choose 3n}$$

I tried putting different values of $n$ and tried to find a pattern in the sum, but was unable to get it.
e.g.

When $n = 1 $ , $Sum =  {6 \choose 0} + {6 \choose 3} = 21$

When $n = 2 $ , $Sum = {12 \choose 0} + {12 \choose 3} + {12 \choose 6} = 1145$

When $n = 3 $ , $Sum = ({18 \choose 0} + {18 \choose 3} + {18 \choose 6}) + {18 \choose 9} = 68001$

Please provide any hint to solve the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "the terms equidistant from either end will be same"? Are $\binom{6n}0$ and $\binom{6n}{3n}$ the same because they are equidistant from either end? Would you know how to solve this if you were asked to sum every _second_ number rather than every _third_? And how familiar are you with complex numbers?

Comment: You can get a vertically centred and properly spaced ellipsis using `\cdots`.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266437/calculating-binomn0-binomn4-binomn8-cdots

Comment: Hint: third roots of unity

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for pointing out my incorrect observation. I quickly reached to that decision looking at 1st and 2nd term. Updating the question. I am familiar with Complex numbers fairly well.

Comment: One of 3Blue1Brown's videos is on this exact topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can you please provide the first line to get started.